# How do I handle different configuration paths on *nix and Windows with chezmoi?

Tags: dotfiles

I want to use [chezmoi](https://www.chezmoi.io/) (or any other dotfile manager). I followed the instructions and added my nvim config on Windows with `chezmoi.exe add ~\AppData\Local\nvim`. The resulting git repository has that very path in it. When I check it out on a *nix machine and apply it with `chezmoi apply`, it creates a directory just like that in my home folder. However, it is expected to be `.config/nvim`.

I thought, chezmoi etc are designed exactly for the purpose of managing dotfiles across diverse machines. How am I supposed to manage that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create templates for each file and then templates for each platform in the respective folder that reference the former. Round it up with some `.chezmoiignore` and you are done. It is all described in the [documentation](https://www.chezmoi.io/user-guide/manage-machine-to-machine-differences/#handle-different-file-locations-on-different-systems-with-the-same-contents).

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this myself. The official answer is not useful for something like neovim, where you have dozens of configuration files. So I ended up simply making a junction from `~/AppData/Local/Nvim` to `~/.config/nvim`.

To do this automatically, make a file with the name `run_after__symlink-neovim-config_windows.ps1` to `~/.local/share/chezmoi`:

```
If ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -Le 5 -Or $isWindows) {
    If (-Not (Test-Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA\nvim)) {
        New-Item -Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA\nvim -ItemType Junction -Value $env:USERPROFILE\.config/nvim
    }
}
```